# Accept multiple input possibilities for a single conditional branch

Tags: ruby

I have this code:

```
choice = $stdin.gets.chomp

if choice == "yes"
  puts "ok sure"
else
  puts "try again"
end
```

I have more than one possibility of user input to put `"ok sure"`. That is, if I input `"ok"`, it should still say `"ok sure"`.

Comment: You could add another `elsif` branch with another condition and instruction.

Comment: You could use `||` or `or` operator please have a look at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm or you might ise elsif or case when as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `case` construction.

```
case choice
when "yes", "ok"
  puts "ok sure"
else
  puts "try again"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to use [Array#include?](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/include%3F) like so:

```
choice = $stdin.gets.chomp

 if ["yes", "ok"].include? choice
   puts "ok sure"
 else
   puts "try again"
 end
```

Comment: This works, but is not the right way to handle this situation.

Comment: @sawa i had a hunch it was possible with `case`, but wasn't sure how. Yeah, I like your answer better honestly.